# Is it possible to forward the output of "service httpd restart" for example to "notify-send $output"?

Tags: linux, terminal, centos

If I create a script that will restart apache:

```
service httpd restart
```

... I will never know what the output was because it does not open the terminal window.

I am wondering if the output can be taken and then forwarded to:

```
notify-send output
```

... this way there is some visual of what happened for few seconds on the screen.

Comment: You could do that with a pipe `service httpd restart 2>&1 | notify-send output` but usually services are started before you login

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, i copy and pasted that, it simply sends "output".

Comment: I think the `javascript`  and `python` tags are not relevant to your question.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, how did you find this post ? was it based on tags of javascript or python ?

Comment: I used the `linux` tag.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, awesome stuff, i can use this code for other things as well, thanks.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, i actually created SVG icons that read "RESTART HTTPD" and so on, and created a new panel for them, now one click and i can see what's up via libnotify as well ( notify-send ) sometimes i just don't wanna see lots of data. just a confirmation that things went through is sufficient for me.

Comment: I believe that having icons to restart services is a bad idea. You really should use terminal for system administration tasks like restarting services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you really should look inside the terminal when running your script.

Also, notice that services are started before login time (at boot time).

And server daemons like Apache or Lighttpd have their own log files usually under `/var/log/`;

You could put the output of `service httpd restart` command into some variable like

```
  restart_msg=$(service httpd restart 2>&1)
```

where `2>&1` redirects *stderr* to *stdout*

then you can show that with

```
  notify-send "HTTPD restarted" "$restart_msg"
```

But I don't think all this is a good idea. You should **take the habit of restarting services inside a terminal** and have a look at the output (in the rare case something gets wrong, you'll need all of it).

Read the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).