# How to properly format this command: Exec=a=$(service httpd restart 2>&1) && notify-send "$a"

Tags: linux, terminal, centos, exec, gnome

I am trying to figure a way to 
fix this code so that `Exec=` line can work properly.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=a
GenericName=a
Exec=a=$(service httpd restart 2>&1) && notify-send "$a"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=/root/Desktop/111.svg
```

this is basically a panel shortcut i created by copying another app's shortcut.

i tested this and it worked great with..

```
Exec=notify-send 'a'
```

in other words it does execute a command.

but i am trying to stuff 2 commands in this line .. as seen above.

Comment: Don't do that. I explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18120830/841108) why.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, there is absolutely nothing wrong with this idea, i only created SVG icons because you can not put TEXT Into panels, maybe in the future centos will upgrade itself and let you add LABELS rather than icons, my svg files look like LABELS. gray bg and etc. so soft. second panel is right under the first panel. imagine for the next 12 years being able to restart httpd with just a click and no longer having to OPEN TERMINAL, TYPE "SERVICE HTTPD RESTART " close terminal, get annoyed by white bg, get confused about multiple terminals, etc.

Comment: The point is that restarting a service is a sysadmin task. Ordinary users should not do it. And sysadmins are working inside terminals. Of course they do develop their own scripts and aliases in their shell environment.

Comment: Create your own shell script to do the job, and put that shell script in the `Exec=` line.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, i auto login as root to centos, i have no idea about those things, this centos everytime it is freshly re-installed, i run all the commands to ensure it auto logs in as root , as far as this thing goes,

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, creating an executable shell script is the fall back option if no-one answers this question, i just think answer might be useful to me later on as well, i usually save the answers for long term stuff. just thought i'd post it to see if i get any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start a wrapper shell, like this:

```
Exec=bash -c "notifiy-send \"$(command)\""
```

Note: Don't miss the double quotes around `$(command)`

What makes in your case:

```
Exec=bash -c "notifiy-send \"$(service http restart)\""
```

Or if the user need to authenticate use `gksu`:

```
Exec=bash -c "notifiy-send \"$(gksu service http restart)\""
```